# Can someone put this decimal expansion equation into layman's terms please?

Tags: decimal-expansion

I am studying this page [on decimal expansion.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecimalExpansion.html) I understand everything up until the strange equation following this sentence.

[image: strange math equation]

The  strange equation is directly above this sentence. I do not think it cares that I am typing about it or that you are looking at it and reading about it. Now, I found a couple of possible meanings for the three horizontal lines.

[image]

According to this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) this is a "congruence relation". This same page defines this symbol and other symbols as meaning "is equal to by definition to" which I think means basically a synonym. Maybe both of these definitions mean the same thing I do not know because this type of math is obviously not my forte. This is why I pointed my web browser to math.stackexchange.com.

Also does the **|** symbol mean "or" as in a programming language or is this a divisor, the division symbol?

My theory, based on the help from a colleague work, is that this means r equals p divided by q. Is this correct?

Then the equation is followed by other equations that somehow prove the equation presumably. These equations are as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do these equations relate to the r equals p divided by q equation? Can someone provide a simple example using these equations or show how they work and what they are used for?

Thank-you for reading this. I apologize for my severe ignorance in these matters.

Comment: The first usage of $\equiv$ on that page in "$r \equiv p/q$" is likely a typo. The other uses are intended, though.

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r \equiv p/q$ simply means "$r$ is equivalent to $\dfrac{p}{q}$". That is, they're saying let $r$ be some rational number $\dfrac{p}{q}$. They then go on to say that if $r $ has a finite decimal expansion (the digits don't go on endlessly after the decimal point), then

$$\begin{array}
\ r &=& \frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10^2}+ \dots + \frac{a_n}{10^n} \\
&=& \frac{a_1 10^{n-1} + a_2 10^{n-2} + \dots + a_n}{10^n} \\
&=& \frac{a_1 10^{n-1} + a_2 10^{n-2} + \dots + a_n}{2^n \cdot 5^n} \\
&=& \frac{p}{2^\alpha 5^\beta}
\end{array}$$

with $p \not\equiv 0 \text{ mod } 5$ and $p \not\equiv 0 \text{ mod } 2$ (meaning $p$ is not divisible by $5$ or $2$).

As an arbitrary example, consider $r=\frac{83148}{100000}=0.83148$. We then have
$$\begin{array}
\ r &=& 0.8 + 0.03+0.001+0.0004+0.00008\\ 
&=& \frac{8}{10}+\frac{3}{10^2}+\frac{1}{10^3}+\frac{4}{10^4}+\frac{8}{10^5} \\
&=& \frac{8 \cdot 10^{4} + 3 \cdot  10^{3} + 1  \cdot 10^{2} + 4 \cdot  10^{1} + 8 }{10^5} \\
&=& \frac{8 \cdot 10^{4} + 3 \cdot  10^{3} + 1  \cdot 10^{2} + 4 \cdot  10^{1} + 8 }{2^5 \cdot 5^5} \\
&=& \frac{20787}{2^3 5^5}
\end{array}$$

The end goal was to show that all numbers with finite decimal expansions can be written in the above form, that is, the form $\frac{p}{2^\alpha 5^\beta}$.

---

Although another instance of $\equiv$ which would make perhaps more sense arrises from modular arithmetic. Consider:
$$8 \equiv 3 \ (\text {mod } 5)$$

This means that $5|(3-8)$, or that the remainder of $\dfrac {3}{5}$ is the same as $\dfrac {8}{5}$. So, perhaps now you see how they're "equivalent".

Comment: Ah, this is enlightening. Thank-you for taking the time to help me understand more Andrew. Could you please give an example of one of the equations? I appreciate what you have done with the modular arithmetic example. Maybe you could add an example for each of the "a 10", equations for lack of a better description. I am still confused about how these relate to the point of decimal expansion.

Comment: @user3870315 I'm glad to help. And sure, let me just type up an edit.

Comment: @user3870315 See my edit.

Comment: Could you please explain the "arbitrary example"? For instance, why are the exponents ordered on the 10s in the denominator sequentially then seemingly in reverse order and in the denominator as the equation expands? Is this some type of math equation I have forgotten since high-school or college? Could you please link to similar math problems?

Comment: Also, 20787/120 equals 1039.35 not 0.83148. 0_o I must sound amazingly stupid and I apologize in advance.